# mobile: get facebook users around in a certain location

Tags: facebook, mobile, gps, mobile-application

I'm new to developing mobile apps, and I'd like some help. I'm trying to create an app that, upon downloading and opening it, tells you nearby Facebook users. Will this have anything to do with the Facebook API? What is the easiest way to do this? Any examples or references would also help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know Facebook not have an option to get the friends by coordinate or something like that,
what you can do is create a database that stores your app users location and when a user logs in to your app you show him results by this database.

Hope it Helps.

Comment: But in that case i always have to update my db.. and i didnt quite understand howd u get a mobile's location?

Comment: you will need to update your DB, and you get the location by this class :https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

Comment: Hmm i didnt say anything about developing to apple devices.. since u sent me to an apple link i wonder if this is related only to apple devices.. in any case sounds like this issue requires a deeper check for discovering the various options

Comment: ohh im sorry
and yes and for sure its something you will have to customize yourself